# Processwire url rewrite

Tags: lighttpd, processwire

I'm looking for the url rewrite configuration for processwire CMS on lighttpd server.

I've tried to translate processwire's .htaccess into lighttpd configuration without successs.

The only discussion I found about it (https://processwire.com/talk/topic/7970-strange-error-in-admin-page-unrecognized-path/) doesn't contain the solution.

I think (but not sure) that the relevant part is:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?it=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I translated in

```
"^(.*)(?:\?(.*))?$" => "/index.php?it=$1&$2"
```

As suggested here: https://redmine.lighttpd.net/boards/2/topics/2259

But still won't work.
Anybody can help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After some testing, this works for me:

```
url.rewrite-if-not-file = (
#Processwire
"^(.*)?\?(.*)?$" => "/index.php?it=$1&$2",
"^(.*)?$" => "/index.php?it=$1",
)
```

1) url.rewrite-if-not-file will allow direct access if the target is a file. Good for .css and .js files, but not so good for other files that should be kept private. Ok for testing, but not for a public website.

2) The first line is for a query containing an interrogation mark (?), the second is for a query without one.

Take this as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks gilbertp, 
I already resolved using this:

```
url.rewrite-if-not-file = (
    "^([^?]*)(?:\?(.*))?$" => "/index.php?it=$1&$2"
)
```

As you said, I need to add extra rows for protecting private areas

Comment: I find it fascinating that lighttpd doesn't separate query strings from the request URI.